# Write a spec for anonymous function

Tags: ocaml

I have anonymous function:

```
fun x -> x;;
- : 'a -> 'a = <fun>
```

As you may see, this function accepts argument of any type. I want to specify concrete type, say int.
I know that I can annotate functions with type specs, but do not know syntax for it.

It would be helpful to get some reference to this syntax and extend this example with such annotation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most general form is:

```
(fun x -> x : int -> int)
```

Since `fun x -> x` is a value by itself, it can be annotated with a type, as any other expression. Indeed, in this type annotation you can omit one of the `int`'s, since the other can be inferred by a compiler:

```
(fun x -> x : int -> 'a)
```

or

```
(fun x -> x : 'a -> int)
```

all will result in:

```
- : int -> int = <fun>
```

This also demonstrates that `'a` in type annotations has different meaning from `'a` in signatures. In type annotation it stands for "I don't care, you decide". Thats why the proper name for type annotations is type constraining, thus you're not annotating your expression with type, but you're giving extra constraint for type inference system. In this example, you're saying to it: I have this expression, and please infer its type, giving it is a function that returns `int`.

Also, you can use `_` instead of type variables, the same way as you can do this for a normal variables:

```
(fun x -> x : _ -> int)
```

The result will be the same.

Answer (score 3):

```
# fun (x: int) -> x;;
- : int -> int = <fun>
#
```

The reason this works is that

- Function parameters are specified as patterns.
- One alternative for a patttern is of the form:

  ( pattern : typexpr )

Syntax for patterns is given in [Section 6.6 of the OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/patterns.html#pattern).